# stack level too deep - when using Rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, rvm

When i try and preform a rake I get the following. I've tried a few fixed like imploding and reinstalling my rvm  - ruby (v1.9.3-p125) but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

```
rake db:seed --trace
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
/Users/rm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:162
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
```

if I try and run a rake db:reset --trace

```
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0025s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(20120803181844,       ["/Users/rossmcnairn/rails/search/db/migrate"])
   -> 0.0218s
** Invoke db:structure:load_if_sql (first_time)
** Invoke db:create 
** Execute db:structure:load_if_sql
** Invoke db:seed (first_time)
** Execute db:seed
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
stack level too deep
/Users/rossmcnairn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:162
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:seed
```

Ive checked that my bundle exec version and my regular rake versions match.

```
rake --version
rake, version 0.9.2.2

bundle exec rake --version
rake, version 0.9.2.2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What happens in your seed file?

Comment: its a little long to paste it in, 1300 lines. But its pretty standard, simply creating DB records.  Yesterday it was seeding without any problems, and without modifying my seed file something else has changed throwing this error up.

Comment: Did something change in appication?

Comment: nothing that should be effecting this.
what do you think this means? /Users/rm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:162
additionally I have recently updated to mountain lion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating OSX is known to give issues in rubies, you should recompile all your rubies:

```
chown -R $USER: $rvm_path
rvm get head
rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p125
rvm all-gesmsets do rvm gemset pristine
```

Also note that any other compiled stuff like libraries needs recompilation, this includes homebrew, macports, `rvm pkg` and any packages you have compiled manually.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, I gave that a go and it seems to have had no impact. Still shooting up the same problems.

Comment: ah we may be getting somewhere, why i tried to recompile every gem shot of the following error. 

actionmailer-3.2.0 ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /Users/rm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/actionmailer-3.2.0/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: try: `chown -R $USER: $rvm_path`

Comment: ahah, that seems to have done the business, how exactly did that work? Thank you!

Comment: The OSX upgrade process had to mess with your directory/files owners, this command has reset ownership for you in $rvm_path

Answer (score 0):

```
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
rake aborted!
```

Did you try to run your migrations?

Answer (score 0):

This may be obvious but it took me a few hours. I unwittingly created a class method for the model called `create`, which is the same as ActiveRecord `create`. So my seed file has circular reference.

I just kept staring at the seed file and wonder why I get the error while I was able to run it twice before (before adding the class method). Moral of the story: naming is important.